# Passing data into a ModalPopupExtender that was opened by Javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit, modalpopupextender

In my code-behind, I open a ModalPopup using javascript

```
javascript: $find('BehaviorID').show()
```

which works fine. But I also need to pass in a username from the selected gridview row so I can get some data from the database and display them.

Overview:

- I have a gridview that displays rows of data.
- I can click on a row to open details about the user(data).
- I need to pass in the username of the selected row to the ModalPopupExtender

How can I achieve this?

I am not at all familiar with javascript by the way but when I see code I understand it so if you have javascript solutions please don't hesitate to share.

Thanks

Here is the code for calling the javascript method

```
e.Row.Attributes.Add("ondblclick", "javascript: $find('BehaviorID').show()");
```

which is in a for loop for each DataRow of the GridView.

Comment: I solved it by not using a Session variable. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Add an Html hidden field that will hold the selected username:

```
<input type="hidden" name="selectedUserName" id="selectedUserName" />
```

In each row hold the username in a control. In the row click event you need to find this control and assign the above hidden input with the row username.

```
function showModalPopup(usernameInputID) {
   document.getElementById('selectedUserName').value = document.getElementById(usernameInputID).value;
   $find('BehaviorID').show();
}
e.Row.Attributes.Add("ondblclick", "javascript: showModalPopup('" + e.Row.FindControl("inpUserName").ClientID + "')");
```

Comment: What is exactly the "e" in e.Row?

Comment: GridViewRowEventArgs which is later used to check if the row is a DataRow

Comment: its not even popping up now. I don't quite get what you mean by usernameInputID though

Comment: inpUserName is the control that holds the username in each row